# Trouble connecting to remote mysql (phpmyadmin) server from java (intellij)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project and I have a java program that parses a bunch of files and breaks them into records which are to be stored within a database. I've tested the program on my own server using the following (intellij generated) string:

[image]

And the above string works fine in the code and all the data is stored

But when I try to connect to the (external) project database located at 104.131.96.199 using the following

[image]

(There are two open ports: 22 and 80)

On port 80 it hangs on "connecting to database" forever (over 10 mins),

and on port 22 I get the packet size error above.

I've gone into phpmyadmin and changed the max_allowed_packet variable to 4739923, but still get the same issue (the change still isn't reflected in the error).

I'm not in charge of this db, although I have the admin user and pass. 
Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated

I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Is my connection string syntactically correct (and if not what should it be)
2. If the string is correct, what to do about the packet size issue / hanging forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Yes, the URL is syntactically correct. If you want to specify a user and password, you can add `?user=<username>&password=<password>` to the end of the String.

2.) It most likely doesnt work because you are apparently using the SSH port (22) and the HTTP port (80) instead of the MySQL port (3306). If these are the only two open ports you will have to ask the server admin to manually allow remote connections to his MySQL server

Comment: Those are the only 2 ports open :/ If I have the admin user and password, would I be able to go onto phpmyadmin and change that myself?

Comment: No, I do not think you can change these values within phpmyadmin. You will have to ssh into the server and comment out the `bind-address: 127.0.0.1` in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: That's above my paygrade :( don't know how to do that. I guess I'll have to contact the admin. Thanks though. That was very helpful

Comment: The problem is that the mysql server only allows connections from itself (for security reasons). With commenting out said line you allow remote connections (e.g. from your computer at home). Personally, I would not do that and rather code my own server application and run it on the server or use php

Comment: Do you just want to read data from the database or do you need write access too?

Comment: write access, as stated in the question

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Well, as I said, you can either ask the admin to open the database for you or write a simple java applicaiton and run it on the server and use sockets for communication.

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax is correct.
2. packet size issue - The changes to max_allowed_packet have possibly not taken effect. Run the below to check the value:

   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

   hanging forever - Check that the port used is correct.

Comment: I typed SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet' and got back 4749312. I checked using Mac's Network utility and the IP has port 22 and port 80 open :/

Comment: To check that the port is open 3306 .. as stated in the answer below, one can use telnet on the cmd: